# Reference on manifolds with corners

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Is there a systematic treatment of (finite dimensional) manifolds with corners in the literature which carefully introduces all usual differential topological notions (submanifolds, embeddings, etc.) and which includes proofs of the usual statements in geometric topology like the existence of collars or isotopy extension theorems in the generality of manifolds with corners?

Most of the common textbooks treat the case without corners nor boundary and mention the case of boundaries. Some of them take care of boundaries more closely, but I am not aware of a detailed reference covering the situation with corners.

Comment: I don't think there's even a consensus on the definition of "manifold with corner". Consider a pyramid with a square base. Is it a manifold with corners? Some people say yes, some people say no because they insist on cubical corners but the top vertex isn't a cubical corner (not locally diffeomorphic to $[0,\infty)^3$).

Comment: I would be interested in literature on both cases, but for me, a manifold with corners is locally modeled on $[0,\infty)^n$.

Comment: @Najib: There is, in my experience, little argument about the type of corners: in everything I've ever seen or used, they're cubical. See 2.1 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3518.pdf) for examples of disagreement over what a manifold with corners is.

Comment: I'm not an expert (therefore I can' guarantee for the references), but google finds some material on [Richard Melrose's personal page](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rbm/book.html). It seems that it was meant for a book the making of which stopped 20 years ago. A recent reference seems to be [this 2010 article by Joyce](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3518v2.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

[Differential Topology](https://www.elsevier.com/books/differential-topology/margalef-roig/978-0-444-88434-3), by Margalef-Roif and Dominguez, builds the standard smooth manifold theory (inverse function theorem, submanifolds, transversality, etc) in the level of generality of Banach manifolds with corners.

I don't actually know a source that deals with isotopy extension and collar neighborhoods. Probably your best bet is just to carefully check the details of what happens in that setting yourself.